# Using a class in joining to database table with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

If I have a summary class of some objects I need ( for example its primary key, etc..) is there a way to use a list of that class object when I am writing a joining to other tables? so all the things in my `LINQ` query are real table like `this.Context.MyTable`  but one of them be my `List<MyClass>` ?
or is there any LINQ related `Nuget` project that makes this possible?

Comment: Can you post an example of what exactly you are trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EF LINQ queries aren't actually code that is run in C#, they are converted to SQL and run on the database server; so you can't join them with an in-memory array (or `List<T>`).  What you can do, is use `Contains` like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Table1> GetThingsFromDatabse(DataContext db, IList<MyObject> objects)
{
    var ids = objects.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    var results = Enumerable.ToList(
        from x in db.Table1s
        where ids.Contains(x.Id)
        select x
    );

    return results;
}
```

This gets translated into SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1] x
WHERE x.Id IN (@Id1, @Id2, ...)
```